# Heroku: NodeJS: pip is missing if I use NodeJS app

Tags: python, node.js, heroku, pip

I have a NodeJS app, in which I want to invoke Python interpreter, to run some processing for me.

When I check for "python --version" from NodeJS using exec(...), I get the output as Python 3.8.5. That's good.
I need to install certain packages using pip.

But when I try to invoke pip, it saying command error. So basically pip is not available on that dyno.

My question is if I use a NodeJS app, how can I install pip? So that I can download certain Python packages.

Comment: is pip in your PATH? You can try pynode https://github.com/fridgerator/PyNode, you can tell it the pasth of the virtual env then it can execute python code. You can install all packages in the virtual env.

Comment: >> is pip in your PATH? 
I don't think it is available on the disk. 
But python3 is in the PATH.

When I ssh into the dyno, and try to do apt-get, it fails, saying read-only disk.

Comment: Can I install pip packages via PyNode?

Comment: Oh if pip is not there then I don't think it is possible to pip install. if pip is not in PATH you can give it full name, normally it resides in <your python>/bin/pip. No pyNode executes python code. You have to give the path of the python interpreter where all the packages are already installed.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app. You need the NodeJS and Python buildpack

Comment: That maybe what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem. You can't install pip, but instead what you need to do is install a python buildpack. This buildpack will set your dyno to properly work with python/pip.

**Using Heroku CLI:**

1. First install python buildpack at the first position: `heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/python`. You should receive the message below:
   [image]
   *NOTE: The buildpack for the primary language of your app should always be the last buildpack in the list. This ensures that defaults for that primary language are applied instead of those for another language, and allows Heroku to correctly detect the primary language of your app.*
2. Second create a commit so you can run `git push heroku main`.

That's it. Now you have pip in your dyno, and if you have a file `requirements.txt` with all the python packages it will be automatically downloaded every time you push to heroku main.

Documentation: [Using Multiple Buildpacks for an App](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app)

Let me know if it worked.